# discrete sum greater than integration

Tags: calculus, integration, discrete-mathematics

Why for any $j \in N$ (the natural numbers) we have
$\sum_{n = j+1}^{j^2} \frac{1}{n} \geq \int_{j+1}^{j^2 + 1} \frac{1}{x} dx $

Comment: Because $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing.

Comment: Draw a picture; the sum is an upper sum for the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, you have that $$\sum_{n=k}^mf(n) \ge \int_k^{m+1}f(x)dx$$ if $f(x)$ is decreasing, and $m \ge k$. This can be seen by splitting the integral into parts as $$\int_k^{m+1}f(x)dx = \sum_{n=k}^m \int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx$$

Then since $f(x)$ is decreasing, you have that $f(n)$ is the maximum value of $f(x)$ for $x \in [n, n+1]$, so the inner integral has an upper bound of $f(n)$. Therefore, the integral has an upper bound of $$\sum_{n=k}^mf(n)$$ which is the original sum.

Comment: This is one of those cases where the picture can tell more than a thousand words. Nice explanation in lieu of the picture though. =D